# How to release memory from multi-threaded script in PowerShell 7.3.3

Tags: multithreading, powershell, memory-management

I wrote a mutli-threaded script in PowerShell 7.3.3 that interacts with Microsoft ExchangeOnline. I use a `RunspacePool` with the option `ReuseThread` to connect to ExchangeOnline and reuse the context for working threads.

```
$outputStream = New-Object -Typename  System.Management.Automation.PSDataCollection[PSObject]
$initialState = [InitialSessionState]::CreateDefault();
$initialState.ImportPSModule("ExchangeOnlineManagement")
$maxThreads = 20
$RunspacePool = [runspacefactory]::CreateRunspacePool($initialState)
$RunspacePool.SetMaxRunspaces($maxThreads);
$RunspacePool.SetMinRunspaces($maxThreads);
$RunspacePool.ThreadOptions = 2 # ReuseThread
$RunspacePool.Open()
[Collections.Arraylist]$traitements = @()
# Create contacts ExchangeOnline
Import-csv $ImportFile -Delimiter ";" | ForEach-Object { 
    $traitements += New-Object -TypeName PSObject -Property @{
        Runspace   = $null
        PowerShell = [powershell]::Create()
    }
    $traitements[-1].PowerShell.RunspacePool = $RunspacePool
    $traitements[-1].PowerShell.AddScript($blockTraitement).AddParameters(@{
            "name"                         = $_.cn
            "email"                        = $_.mail
            "firstName"                    = $_.givenName
            "lastName"                     = $_.surName
            "extensionAttribute4"          = $_.extensionAttribute4
            "msExchSenderHintTranslations" = $_.msExchSenderHintTranslations
            "description"                  = $_.Description
            "title"                        = $_.title
            "company"                      = $_.company
            "postalcode"                   = $_.postalcode
            "city"                         = $_.l
            "departement"                  = $_.departement
        })
    $traitements[-1].Runspace = $traitements[-1].PowerShell.BeginInvoke()
}

# EndInvoke and dispose
while ($traitements) {
    foreach ($runspace in $traitements.ToArray()) {
        if ($runspace.Runspace.IsCompleted) {
            Write-Host "RUNSPACE is completed " + $runspace.Runspace.IsCompleted
            $outputStream = $runspace.PowerShell.EndInvoke($runspace.Runspace)
            $outputStream | ForEach-Object {
                Write-Host $_
            }
            $runspace.PowerShell.Stop()
            $runspace.PowerShell.Dispose()
            $traitements.Remove($runspace)
        }
        Start-Sleep -Milliseconds 100
    }
}

$outputStream.Dispose()
$RunspacePool.Close()
$RunspacePool.Dispose()
Clear-Variable -Name initialState,RunspacePool,traitements,outputStream -Confirm:$false
Remove-Variable -Name initialState,RunspacePool,traitements,outputStream -Confirm:$false
[System.GC]::Collect()
[System.GC]::WaitForPendingFinalizers()
[System.GC]::Collect()
```

When the processing is done, I close, dispose and remove all variables to release memory. But PowerShell keeps the memory (`7Gb`)

Am I missing something ?

Comment: how many lines does your csv have? You're creating an instance per line of your CSV, instead you should group the objects in chunks and pass them to a fixed number of threads to process them

Comment: also, since you're on 7.3.3 why are you using runspacepool ? `ForEach-Object -Parallel` and `ThreadJob` are available and will do a much better an efficient job

Comment: Probably a simple pipeline where you do a `Connect-ExchangeOnline` in the `begin` block, using the `process` block for each setting and `Disconnect-ExchangeOnline` in the `end` block will already make a large performance difference. See: [Mastering the (steppable) pipeline](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/powershell-community/mastering-the-steppable-pipeline/)

Comment: @SantiagoSquarzon, I tried using `ForEach-Object -Parallel` but it seems less efficient because I need to call `Connect-ExchangeOnline` first. I would be glad to see how you used `-Parallel` with `ExchangeOnline`

Comment: @iRon very interesting solution, I  will try to implement it and will update the post if works great

Comment: I dont know about ExchangeOnline module I just know with your current code if your CSV has 1k lines you would be creating 1k pwsh instances at once which is incredibly inefficient. You should create at tops just 8 instances and pass each instance a chunk of work to process

Comment: @SantiagoSquarzon you were right. Using limited number of instances makes the code more efficient and I saw a reduction of memory consumption, thank you for that. Still, memory is not released even after garbage collection